# spring redis topic subscribe cache

Tags: java, spring, redis, publish-subscribe

I use spring-redis publish-subscribe. It received message without delay at the beginning of running my code. But after about few minutes not receiving message, it won't response immediately (don't know when it can receive again, almost can't receive)! So I were wondering - is there a cache setting or something?

```
@Configuration
public class PubSubConfiguration {

    @Bean
    RedisMessageListenerContainer container(RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
        MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter) {

        RedisMessageListenerContainer container = new RedisMessageListenerContainer();
        container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        container.addMessageListener(listenerAdapter, new PatternTopic("topic"));
        return container;
    }

    /**
     * @param receiver
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter(Sub1 receiver) {
        return new MessageListenerAdapter(receiver);
    }
}


@Component
public class Pub1 {

    @Autowired
    private StringRedisTemplate stringRedisTemplate;

    public void testCheckpoint() {
        stringRedisTemplate.convertAndSend("topic", "2018-07-09");
        System.out.println("sent...");
    }
}


@Component
public class Sub1 implements MessageListener {

    @Override
    public void onMessage(final Message message, final byte[] pattern) {
        String msg = new String(message.getBody());
        String topic = new String(message.getChannel());
        System.out.println(String.format("time: %s, msg: %s, topic: %s", LocalTime.now(), msg, topic));
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it maybe because exception occurred when handling a message on method - onMessage(). But I publish the same message all the time... So confusing. Now, I already use Jedis instead, working fine by now. I will be back if it works.

Comment: Jedis has the same issue....

Comment: When I set timeout to 0, it occurred SocketExcption: Connection reset.....